# how to determine that mpg321 finished playing a file

Tags: c, linux

I am plying music using mpg321 in remote mode from C:

```
FILE* pipe = popen("mpg321 -R abcd > /dev/null 2>&1", "w");
```

then load a file using:

```
fprintf(pipe, "LOAD test.mp3\n", buf); 
fflush(pipe);
```

Now I need to know when mpg321 finished to play the file. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of mpg321 are you using? eof detection is only available in 0.2.9

Answer (score 0):

When you're done writing to your pipe, you have to close it using `pclose()`, which will wait for the child process to terminate and return its exit status.  So when your `pclose()` call returns, you know that mpg321 has finished running.